# Meaning of the new tech to future politics - AI, blockchain and Co. - reference to expert estimations?

Tags: government, reference-request

My impression is that most politicians are not able to qualify what is actually happening through the new tech - neither myself and probably nobody.

But then, what will happen through this tech becoming available to everybody? After all, all of it is open source and publicly available.

I see three scenarios two of them are not much more to consider because they will be nothing new in the human history:

- New tech will be abandoned as easiest solution
- New tech will be regulated to a form which will create evil dictatorships
- New tech will be adopted by democratic civil governments

So this third option gives me some thought on:

- what if all the money will become some sort of Bitcoin?
- what if all the business will become some sort of a mix of AI and blockchain?
- what if citizens will run DAOs?
- what if political advisory will be supported by public AIs - if they write about AI board members to process and accumulate data, why shouldn't a government do this?

Are there established argumentations / known works on the level of content produced by World Economic Forum but on a larger scale and not being just a speculation but maybe linked to data simulation?

Comment: This post is very interesting, but it is very broad (some may write books to tackle this subject). Please, try to narrow it to make it more answerable.

Comment: @Alexei thanks - as more experienced individual on this forum please give me a hint which dimensions of narrowing down the question to become a) most likely answerable and answered b) not less interesting c) less broad

Comment: @J.Doe Such speculative questions about the future are a bad fit for stackexchange. We prefer questions which have answers which can be verified as correct or incorrect. Predictions about the future are notoriously unreliable, even when they come from experts.

Comment: @Philippj - actually WEC is working in this direction, still my perception they do not do enough there. I try here with a reference request?

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer all of your questions, but I can give a brief answer to 'what if all money becomes some sort of Bitcoin':

If all money was like Bitcoin there would be wide-reaching changes in nations' economic policies. Bitcoin is designed so that there are a finite number of Bitcoins and finding Bitcoins becomes harder as more Bitcoins are found.

If this is the case and most people in a nation are using Bitcoin as currency then, because Bitcoins can't be produced at will, governments lose the power to increase liquidity by printing money (as they are currently able to do and have done so recently with so called 'quantitative easing').

If governments are unable to increase liquidity by printing money then they lose the default method of dealing with situations where money is in short supply, and this is a serious problem.

You can imagine various scenarios that might occur if Bitcoin or similar virtual currencies became widely adopted, for example: governments might try to stockpile virtual currencies to enable them to control supply; governments might increase taxes and public spending to give themselves more control over money; governments might try to outlaw the use or possession of virtual currencies, or an international central bank might emerge to regulate the supply of virtual currency to nations.

Since all of these scenarios seem problematic for governments I don't expect virtual currencies will replace existing currencies any time soon.

Comment: Good points! Now virtual currencies are mainly used by those who benefit from its anonymity (e.g. extortion money, drug payments, tax evasion). Thus I would assume that one of the first things governments will try to do, when crypto currencies get more popular, is mandating all citizens to have only one account (per currency) and submitting it to their local taxation authority. If payments can't be tracked down then illegal actions can't be stopped...

Comment: Adding to this: Bitcoin and the like is usually not viewed as a good idea by economists for this reason: Say the size of your country doubles. Twice the amount of people now produce twice the amounts of goods. But if you still have the same amount of money then the prices will half. Similar things happen when your economy simply grows. So fixed volumes in currency tends to be deflationary. And deflation is usually viewed as very unhealthy for countries, as it reduces demand and can lead to a recession.

Comment: So having a Central Bank which can adjust the amount of money depending on GDP is helpful. An obvious question would be: can algorithms not do that? Yes and no, as inflation is measured with consumer baskets. And those baskets kind of need to be defined by humans. Being able to tax wealth with seigniorage is an added benefit of currency in state hands.